# Google Apps Script Writing to Spreadsheet Column One Step Behind

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Weird problem here. I'm writing a script using Google Apps Scripts. Part of the script takes values from 1 Range/array ("a"), finds the value in a second Range/array ("b"), and then writes the corresponding value from a 3rd Range/array ("c") into column F in the spreadsheet. It's basically a vlookup.

When I check the code, debugger, etc. everything looks fine. And the output into the sheet looks good too. Except when I ran the program, the last value was missing from the sheet. When I ran the program slowly using the debugger, it seems that for some reason the values aren't being printed to column F until the following round of the loop is complete. This doesn't really make any sense based on the values of the variables at the time. So for example, when i=4, it should be printing to F6. But instead it prints the previous value to F5. All of the correct values are in the correct place in the end (except the last one), but the timing seems to be off on when that happens which is why I'm missing my last value.

Note: I have tried seeing if it's just about a time delay, and that doesn't seem to be the case. I've reloaded the spreadsheet, waited a while, etc. It's just 1 step behind.

Code is below, pretty simple I think. Any help would be appreciated

```
loop1:
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    loop2:
    for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
      if(a[i].valueOf() == b[j].valueOf()){
        sheet.getRange("F"+(i+2)).setValue(c[j]);
        break loop2;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-create your situation with the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var a = ['one','6','match'];
  var b = ['two','Vee','match'];
  var c = ['three','Vee','match'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  loop1:
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      loop2:
      for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
        //Logger.log('a[i].valueOf() ' + a[i])
        //Logger.log('b[j].valueOf() ' + b[j])

        Logger.log(a[i].valueOf() == b[j].valueOf());
        if (a[i].valueOf() == b[j].valueOf()) {
          Logger.log('they match!');
          Logger.log('i: ' + i);
          Logger.log('j: ' + j);
          sh.getRange("F"+(i+2)).setValue(c[j]);
          break loop2;
        }
      }
    }
};
```

The code runs, and it puts a value into cell F4 with the array data provided.

The Log:

```
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
true
they match!
i: 2
j: 2
```